# FileReader read() method is printing imporperly. Do I need to do any additional conversion besides int(ASCII rep) to char?

Tags: java, filereader

Trying to print the read() output of the same program on to the console, the characters are either missing or disarranged. Tried this for different files too, getting the same issue.

The byte Stream class and method,FileInputStream.read()for the same type of code,  worked perfectly fine, but this character stream is resulting differently.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

class CSRead1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("Enter the filename\t>"); 
        String file = input.next();

        try(FileReader fr = new FileReader(file))
        {   while(fr.read() != -1)
            {out.print((char)fr.read());} } //***reading improperly
    }
}
```

Got this upon execution:

```
D:\JavaEx\FILE-IO>java CSRead1
Enter the filename      >CSRead1.java
ipr aaui.cne;
{asCRa1aaln.ytm*
pbi ttcvi anSrn[ rs hosIEcpin
{
        cne nu  e cne(n;
        u.rn(Etrteflnm\>)
        tyFlRae r=nwFlRae(ie)
                hl(rra( =-)
        {u.rn(ca)rra()}}/**edn mrpry

}
?
```

For a text file containing the only string "Hello"

```
D:\JavaEx\FILE-IO>java CSRead1
Enter the filename      >sample
el?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read two chars on every iteration: one in `while` condition and one in loop body. try to fix this issue and all your code will work fine.

Comment: "will work fine" as long as he's not using UTF-8, or any encoding other than pure ASCII or Latin1.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes, you're right. it will be new challenge

Comment: @Sergey Thank you, retried like this, now works perfectly fine
 int i;
 while((i=fr.read()) != -1)
 {out.print((char)i);}
I was able to notice that it was reading every other character upon verifying with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I once had an issue with reading files with UTF-8 encoded characters in them.
The solution was:

```
String st;
File filedir = new File(filename);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new 
FileInputStream(filedir), "UTF8"));
while((st = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(st); //prints out properly on my side
}
```

within your code it would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
    out.print("Enter the filename\t>"); 
    String file = input.next();

    String st;
    File filedir = new File(file );
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new 
    FileInputStream(filedir), "UTF8"));
    while((st = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(st);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually,  int i; while((i=fr.read()) != -1)  {out.print((char)i);} fixed it; earlier I didn't use the a field i to store the returned int, as you did with String st, and it was skipping every other character

Comment: Alright good to hear that. Does it read UTF-8 properly aswell? 
If you want you can test the code above aswell and feel free to upvote if you found it useful

Comment: Thank you, it was definitely useful have an upvote from me:) Looks like FileReader's constructor doesn't take 2 string arguments unlike BufferedReader , I'll refer your answer once I start working with BufferedReader